# CASE Statements with multiple values

Tags: sql, db2, case, toad

Hi I want to write a CASE STATEMENT like this:

```
CASE
WHEN A in ('AA','AV') and B = 'HH' then 'R'
```

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR [42803] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] An expression starting with "B" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.

But I don't have "B" in my select clause.

Comment: Please share the sql you are submitting

Comment: It's a 9 page SQL, I can't share the whole code. but when I do    CASE WHEN A = 'AA' and B = 'HH' then 'R'    WHEN A = 'AV' and B= 'HH' then 'R', it works fine.

Comment: The error doesn't come from this snippet. Can you please share the entire query?

Comment: Yes, you do. `B = 'HH'`.

Comment: I just want to combine the CASE STATEMENTS

Comment: You've tagged oracle and SQL Server here, however, your error implies DB2. I'll remove the conflicting DBMS tags. Please update and tag correctly.

Comment: What do you mean "I don't have "B" in my select clause"? It's right here `and B = 'HH'`. The error references the `B` column in your CASE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `CASE` statement is part of a SELECT, ORDER BY, or HAVING clause.

For this error, in conjuction with this code, you must also have a GROUP BY clause. You need to include `B` as part of that group by clause. Otherwise, `B` represents a whole range of possible values, some of which might or might not meet the `= 'HH'` condition; the code is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the error. I had to make these changes in the "Group by" statement at the bottom too that I hadn't made and I was getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need `END`  after then value

```
select CASE
WHEN A in ('AA','AV') and B = 'HH' then 'R' end
```

General syntax for CASE

```
CASE expression
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
   ...
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but it doesn't help in my case. I appreciate you trying to help. Cheers!